# Connecting libKeyFinder to max patch, or connecting keyfinder.app

Tags: max

I came across a [max device](https://maxforlive.com/library/device/7444/diff-devices-keymatch) where the author uses a [desktop app](https://www.ibrahimshaath.co.uk/keyfinder/) for key detection, is it possible to implement the [library](https://github.com/mixxxdj/libKeyFinder) into my max patch?

It's worth mentioning that I'm looking for a simple way since I don't know programming.

Or how can I repeat this trick with connecting a desktop application to send .wav files / path to it and extract the received note from it?

I could buy this device to understand it, but I already have some devices from this author and they all have protection.